# Android and twitter : get timeline of particular "ScreenName" in Collection using RestAPI

Tags: android, twitter

I want to display tweets from a particular `@screenname` in a `RecyclerView`, *in my own way*.. I need the collection of tweets so that I can fetch the necessary information from it, and load it in `RecyclerView`.

How can I make a REST API CALL for getting timeline using any of the networking client, `Volley`, `AsyncHttpClient` or `Retrofit`?

I didn't find any solution.. I googled it.. but all the links redirected me to [GET collections/list](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/collections/list)

And I am not able to figure out how to use this... :(

Comment: used `Retrofit` for that. for that you must register app in twitter

Comment: @MD Ohh.. sounds great.. Thank you sir.. Can you provide me some links to this ?

Comment: No i dont have any link but i recently developed my own `StackOverflow App` by using `Stack Exchange API 2.2` by `Retrofit 2.0`. Please [Look at this](https://github.com/manishpatelgt/MyStackOverflowRepo)

Comment: @MD Right sir.. everythings done sir.. I have following keys: Twitter API key, Consumer key and Consumer Secret.

Comment: Ok wait let me try one thing..

Comment: @MD Okay sir.. I'm waiting..